# Multiple request received by node server, while the react client is sending only one

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, pm2

I am facing a really weird problem. I have developed and deployed a betting website on node, express and react(nginx and pm2 has been used used in deployment). The react client send request to node server to place a bet and then server places the bet after its validation. Now, it is executing perfectly in all machines except few. When a vivo 1919 smartphone places a bet using chrome then one request is send by the react but the server receives two requests and simultaneously places two bets with very small time differences. On the other hand when it places bet using firefox the server receives only one request for one request sent by the react app. All other devices as per my reach gives desirable result other then vivo 1919, google chrome. Please suggest how can I approach this problem.

Comment: Did you see it in developer tools remotely to see what is happening?

Comment: i just logged the data in front end and backend, it logged twice on server side and once in client side for the case mentioned above.

Comment: We have experienced something similar, but in our case it was majorly because of button not getting disabled and UI firing two apis as the end user was using double click.

Comment: maybe then i should handle double click events